# |Missing| tag. Leave or prune?

Tags: discussion, support

Just noticed a question that was tagged as [web] [missing] [part] (yes, 3 separate tag).
The question is [WebPart Does Not show up in Gallery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/50826/revisions).

I have edited/corrected the tags on the question, but I wonder what to do with the [Missing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing) tag. Should we leave it, improve it with a description to give it some actual use or just leave nature do its course and let it be pruned by the system if no one will use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it. The tag comes from questions that get migrated here from other sites (like StackOverflow).

Comment: aaaaaah, I was of the idea that it was added by the user when typing a phrase in place of the appropiate tags ("Missing Web Part"). You should be right, I was misguided by the fact that for an astral coincidence (maybe mayas?) the tag wasn't used anywhere else.